# Android library for communicating with AB PLCs

Tags: android, plc

I would like to ask if anybody has an idea with a library that can communicate with Allen Bradley PLCs or if anybody has an idea as to how to communicate with Allen Bradley PLCS.

My idea is to create a socket connection between the android device and the PLC and I already know the port number but the problem is I do not know the format of parameters to pass when communicating with the PLC. For example I want to send a BOOLEAN parameter to switch the machine on/off.

If anybody has an idea please feel free to share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any android libraries for communicating with AB PLCs, but there are plenty of libraries in a variety of different languages.

First you need to figure out the model of your PLC and how you want to communicate with it, via serial or ethernet.

You would typically use DF1 as your serial protocol. Another possibility is to use modbusRTU.

If you want to communicate through ethernet you will want to look up Ethernet/IP protocol. Be aware that the Ethernet/IP protocol for the Micrologix/SLC family differes from the Ethernet/IP protocol for the CompactLogix/ControlLogix family.
Again, depending on your model you could use modbusTCP. Some will have the protocol built in, and some wont.

Comment: Yes I do want to communicate through Ethernet/IP and I already found a library but it is written for Java application so I need to edit some codes because there are classes that does not exist in Android.